# How can i determine u here

Tags: abstract-algebra, gaussian-integers

The Gaussian integer $3-5i$ can be written as a product $3-5i = u\times p\times q$
, there
u is a unit and
and p,q
are Gaussian primes in standard form. Decide u.

How can i determine u here by factorize 3-5i here?
I have tried $3^2+5^2 = 34 => 2 \times 17 => (1+i)\times(1+4i)$ is this correct how can i calculate u?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What happened in the next step, when you computed the product $(1+i) \times (1+4i)$?

Comment: I thought that you could represent 2 as (1+i) and 17 as (1+4i) please tell me if this is correct how to determine u?